# Css math functions (calc, min, max, clamp) not working on Edge Android?

Tags: android, css, max, microsoft-edge, min

I am writing a demo using CSS `clamp()` for `width` property and found that:

It *works* properly on desktop Edge, Chrome, Firefox.

It *works* properly on Android Chrome, Firefox, iOS Safari.

It *does not work* on Android Edge and UC Browser.

(Edge supposed to work due to using the same Blink engine with Chrome, as far as I know...)

When using Edge Remote Debug, I found that the `width: clamp(...);` declaration was *invalid*, no matter what the parameters were.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G06eK.png)

After trying, even `min()`, `max()`, and `calc()` are invalid, which is strange. According to MDN and Caniuse, these math functions() should be supported already.

Hopefully someone can shed light on this, thanks.

Comment: Are you check the Edge vesion on your android device?

Comment: @sungyong Yes, it was the latest.

Comment: I suggest you try to provide feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue by using the Edge for Android browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It is stuck on pretty old Chromium `version (70x)`, so we can do nothing until they update it.